# How to do a FOR loop properly in batch script in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I am trying to convert from a bash script, this is what I came up with.
When I try to run this, I get `the syntax of the command is incorrect` error. I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/how-do-you-loop-in-a-windows-batch-file) and wrote the commands.What is wrong with this batch script?

```
REM This scripts downloads the mnist data and unzips it.
SET wget="../../tools/3rdparty/bin/wget.exe"
SET gunzip="../../tools/3rdparty/bin/gunzip.bat"

ECHO "Downloading..."

FOR %%G IN (train-images-idx3-ubyte train-labels-idx1-ubyte t10k-images-idx3-ubyte t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte)
DO
    %wget% --no-check-certificate http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/%%G.gz
    %gunzip% %%G.gz

ECHO "Done."
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
REM This scripts downloads the mnist data and unzips it.
SET wget="../../tools/3rdparty/bin/wget.exe"
SET gunzip="../../tools/3rdparty/bin/gunzip.bat"

ECHO "Downloading..."

FOR %%G IN (train-images-idx3-ubyte train-labels-idx1-ubyte t10k-images-idx3-ubyte t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte) DO (
    %wget% --no-check-certificate http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/%%G.gz
    %gunzip% %%G.gz
)
ECHO "Done."
```

If you use many commands in for loop you need to enclose in () brackets.